# How to pass variable filename to python ete?

Tags: python, variables, tree, etetoolkit

I am trying load newick string from a file using following code:

```
filename = templist[1].lower().replace(" ","") + ".nwk"
tt = Tree(filename, format=1)
```

but getting following error:

```
 tt = Tree(filename, format=1) # Loads a tree structure from a newick string. The returned variable tt is the root node for the tree.
  File "/python2.7/dist-packages/ete2-2.2.1072-py2.7.egg/ete2/coretype/tree.py", line 225, in __init__
    read_newick(newick, root_node = self, format=format)
  File "/python2.7/dist-packages/ete2-2.2.1072-py2.7.egg/ete2/parser/newick.py", line 237, in read_newick
    'Unexisting tree file or Malformed newick tree structure.'
ete2.parser.newick.NewickError: Unexisting tree file or Malformed newick tree structure.
```

I have verified the file format, and it is Ok. I think I am passing the variable in wrong way, can you please guide me to pass filename as variable.

When I pass the filename as string without using variable it is working fine, but I need to use variable value to load tree.

Comment: Show us where the filename is defined.

Comment: filename = templist[1].lower().replace(" ","") - this is just computed from list, and gets a string with only a-z chars

Comment: Can you print out the filename and check if it does give you the result you want?

Comment: Yes i did, its working correctly, i even used the filename and checked if tree structure is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the `format=1` is correct?

According to [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/ete2/tutorial/tutorial_trees.html#trees) -

> for named internal nodes we will use format 1

Are you sure your newick tree has named internal nodes? If not, try without passing any value to the `format` argument.

---

Also, please make sure that the filename is either `absolute` path to the file, or if its relative path , for example `a.nwk` , then make sure the file exists in the directory from which you are running the python script.

Comment: Yes, its all working fine with string. Pretty sure problem is with the way variable is being passed

Comment: templist = ['00Outdoor', 'TENNIS']
filename = tennis.nwk

Comment: are you sure it is in the same folder , from where you are running the script?

Comment: Yes, thanks its working now, code was running in loop and one file was not in same folder.